# ¿como hacer una consulta JOIN en RoR usando PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Tengo estas tres tablas en PostgreSQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago una consulta directa PostgreSQL y camina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer una consulta equivalente con `JOIN` en *RoR* y me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el controlador tengo esto:

```
class RopasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ropa, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def todo
    todo = Maestro.traeTodo
    puts "======================"
    puts todo.inspect
    puts "======================"
  end
end
```

En el modelo tengo esto:

```
class Maestro < ApplicationRecord

    def self.traeTodo
        self.joins(:ropa, :color).select('self.id, ropa.nombre, color.nombre')
        # sql = "SELECT m.id, m.ropa_id, m.color_id
        #        FROM public.maestros AS m
        #        INNER JOIN public.ropas  AS r ON r.id = m.ropa_id
        #        INNER JOIN public.colors AS c ON c.id = m.color_id"
        # find_by_sql(sql)
    end

end
```

¿alguna idea que me ayude a salir de este atolladero?

**ACTUALIZACION**

Se adjuntan estas líneas para mostrar mejor la consulta de la [respuesta de Gerry](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/290980/42433) del resultado del `inspect`, me trae solos los `id` de la tabla `maestros`:

```
Maestro Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  maestros.id, ropas.nombre AS ropa, colors.nombre AS color FROM "maestros" INNER J
pas" ON "ropas"."id" = "maestros"."ropa_id" INNER JOIN "colors" ON "colors"."id" = "maestros"."color_id" LIMIT $1
MIT", 11]]
  ? app/controllers/ropas_controller.rb:18
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Maestro id: 2>, #<Maestro id: 1>, #<Maestro id: 4>, #<Maestro id: 3>]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Únicamente puedes utilizar `joins` con asociaciones del modelo, en tu ejemplo faltan dos:

```
belongs_to :color
belongs_to :ropa
```

Además, debes considerar lo siguiente al utilizar `select':

- Utiliza el **nombre de la tabla**, no de la asociación.
- Especifica un *alias* para por lo menos una de las columnas que se llaman igual (ie. `nombre`), de lo contrario solo verás la información de una de ellas.

Así quedaría tu modelo:

```
class Maestro < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :color
  belongs_to :ropa

  def self.trae_todo
    self.joins(:ropa, :color).select("maestros.id, ropas.nombre AS 'ropa', colors.nombre AS 'color'")
  end
end
```

*Cambié el nombre del método para seguir las convenciones de Ruby.*

> ..me trae solos los ID de la tabla maestro:
>
> `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Maestro id: 2>, #<Maestro id: 1>, #<Maestro id: 4>, #<Maestro id: 3>]>`

`inspect` te mostrará los atributos del modelo elegidos en el `select` (i.e. `id`), pero la información del *query* está completa en cada registro, para poder verla necesitas utilizar el método `[]`; ejemplo:

```
primer_maestro = Maestro.trae_todo.first
primer_maestro["ropa"]
#=> "pantalon"

primer_maestro["color"]
#=> "azul"
```

Comment: Saludos amigo Gerry, copiando tu consulta, le quité las comillas simples, porque daba un error, corregido esto, me da esta salida que edito en la pregunta para que la puedas ver mejor

Comment: @rrg1459  He actualizado la respuesta para explicar como obtener los valores de la consulta.

Comment: Me hiciste parir, no quería borrar tus ediciones que son muy acertadas, espero no haberlas borrado, funciona perfecto. Gracias